# Coding a discord bot with old school MUD emote's

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm hoping someone can assist me with what I thought should be an easy project despite my lack of coding experience.

I am trying to add some old school MUD emotes to my discord server and the response should vary depending if a target it mentioned or not.

For instance, assuming I have a John and Jane Doe in my server and John is typing I would like;

?smile to return "John smiles" AND
?smile @Jane to return "John smiles @Jane" or at least "John smiles at Jane"

additionally I have come to realize this may be complicated by the fact that the name(s) would not always be at the start or end of the return.

I.e. ?swing might return "John swings around in a circle like a fool"
whereas ?swing @Jane might return "John grabs @Jane by the hands and swings them around in a circle, weeee"

I was thinking the below should work but it simply does not, any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
@bot.command()
async def prod(ctx, *, user: discord.Member = None):
if user:
    await ctx.send(f"prods {user.mention} in the ribs, ouch")
else:
    await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.nickname} prods themselves, what a wierdo")
```

Comment: What issue are you having?

Comment: Is it an indentation error?

Answer (score 0):

if I get it correctly you want a command that if a user is given, the command will have something to do with that user and if no user is given he does that thing on himself.

What your doing wrong is that the object `ctx.author` has no attribute `nickname` (as stated in the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=author#discord.Message.author)).

This would be a working way to do it:

```
@bot.command()
async def prod(ctx, user: discord.Member = None):
    if (user == ctx.message.author or user == None):
        await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention} prods themselves, what a wierdo")
    else:
        await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention} prods {user.mention} in the ribs, ouch")
```

Comment: That did it thank you!

Comment: no problem, happy to help @BruceTaylor